The method of drawing 3D shapes that stack each other allows the shapes to be rotated without overlapping lines
I'm trying to draw adjacent cubes like this:
When I rotate the shape I just drew, it gets distorted due to the order of drawing the cubes. The lines of the later shapes overlap the earlier ones. Is there any way to solve this issue?
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{50}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [tdplot_main_coords,
            cube/.style={very thick,black},
            grid/.style={very thin,gray},
            axis/.style={->,blue,thick}]

    %draw a grid in the x-y plane
    \foreach \x in {-1,0,...,4.5}
        \foreach \y in {-1,0,...,4.5}
        {
            \draw[grid] (\x,-1) -- (\x,4.5);
            \draw[grid] (-1,\y) -- (4.5,\y);
        }
            

    %draw the axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (8,0,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,8,0) node[anchor=west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,8) node[anchor=west]{$z$};

    %draw the edges of the cube
    \foreach \x/\y/\z in {0/2/0,0/1/0,0/0/0}
    {
    \draw [fill=gray!30] (\x,\y,\z)--++(0,0,1)--++(0,1,0)--++(0,0,-1)--cycle;    %x
    \draw [fill=gray!30] (\x,\y,\z)--++(1,0,0)--++(0,1,0)--++(-1,0,0)--cycle;    %z
    \draw [fill=gray!30] (\x,\y,\z)--++(1,0,0)--++(0,0,1)--++(-1,0,0)--cycle;    %y
    \draw [fill=gray!30] (\x,\y+1,\z)--++(1,0,0)--++(0,0,1)--++(-1,0,0)--cycle;    %y
    \draw [fill=gray!30] (\x+1,\y,\z)--++(0,0,1)--++(0,1,0)--++(0,0,-1)--cycle;    %x
    \draw [fill=gray!30] (\x,\y,\z+1)--++(1,0,0)--++(0,1,0)--++(-1,0,0)--cycle;    %z
    }
    
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



